# Custom css checkbox tick displaying differently between two tables

Tags: html, css, checkbox

So I am building a settings page where users can change their settings (duh) and a big part is the privacy check box (if they want something to be private or displayed) so I am currently building the custom checkbox for users to click.

But one issue: the tick is showing differently in the sidebar compared to the main content? it is targeting the same code, and it is not being over ridden as there is 1 stylesheet for the checkbox, and the word checkbox does not even appear in any other stylesheet.

here is an example of what I mean:

[image: ticks different in sidebar compared to main content]

here is the stylesheet for the checkbox (I am breaking them up as my main stylesheet already has 850+ lines of code...):

```
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]{
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 2;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + span,
input[type="radio"] + span{
border:1px solid #c4f0f6;
/*border-radius: 4px;*/
/*box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #c4f0f6;*/
display: inline-block;
height:18px;
margin-bottom:-4px;
margin-right:6px;
width:18px;
background-color: #c4f0f6;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span,
input[type="radio"]:checked + span{
border-color:#c4f0f6;
/*box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #8bf0b5;*/
position: relative;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:after,
input[type="radio"]:checked + span:after{
/*background-color:#43a6b5;
border-radius: 2px;*/
position: absolute;
content:'✔';
display: block;
height:15px;
margin: 1px 0 0 3px;
width: 10px;
}


input[type="radio"] + span,
input[type="radio"]:checked + span:after{
/*border-radius: 50%;*/
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label, input[type="radio"]:checked ~  label{color:#25c266;}
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + span, input[type="radio"]:disabled + span{border- color: #dedede;/*box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #efefef;*/}
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + span:after, input[type="radio"]:disabled +      span:after{background-color:#dedede;}
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled ~ label, input[type="radio"]:disabled ~      label{color:#b2bbc0;}
#main_details_change label, #privacy_settings label, #notifications_settings label {  display: none; }
```

thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: It will be easier to answer if you create a fiddle.

Comment: Try learning how to use the webkit dev tools (or even mozilla's dev tools). Inspecting the checkbox should indicate where the different color values come from and which properties might have been ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a typo in the stylesheet:

```
border- color: #dedede;
```

instead of

```
border-color: #dedede;
```

If that is not the case, check for the 'color' style of the parents where the checkboxes are looking different. It may be getting inherited and the only difference in the checkboxes that I could make out is their 'color'.